# How can I get the values of an ASP Listbox Control which are added in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an asp.net lisbox control and I'm adding the data from the client side javascript with this code;

```
function selectCompany() {
   var str = document.getElementById('<%= txtFollowing.ClientID %>').value;
   var lbRef = document.getElementById('<%= lbCompanies.ClientID %>');
   var option = document.createElement("option");
   option.text = str;
   option.value = str;
   lbRef.options.add(option);
}
```

The items are added with no problem, but in the code behind, when I want to get the values of  items which are in the list box, it is always null, how can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Because you added the items to the control dynamically, it is not part of the viewstate tree; you will need to access the items using the Request.Form collection

```
Request.Form("Your_Listbox_ID")
```

If you do not know "Your_Listbox_ID", set a breakpoint and do a quickwatch on Request.Form, have a quick look through its key names.

Alternatively, you may consider adding a hidden field to the page and writing the selected values (or all the values) to the hidden field and reading the hidden field from the codebehind.